# Azure CI Blazor Webassembly build error after update to Net 5.0

Tags: c#, azure, build, blazor, .net-5

After updating my Blazor Webassembly project to .Net 5.0 I get an error in the Azure CI build:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Copying the minified builld styles to WWWROOT
  Client -> /github/workspace/Client/bin/Release/net5.0/Client.dll
  Client (Blazor output) -> /github/workspace/Client/bin/Release/net5.0/wwwroot
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
/tmp/oryx/platforms/dotnet/5.0.100/sdk/5.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.Current.targets(548,5): error MSB6006: "/tmp/oryx/platforms/dotnet/5.0.100" exited with code 1. [/github/workspace/Client/Client.csproj]
```

I have no problems to build and start the project on my local Visual Studio 16.18.2

The .yml file:

```
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_PROUD_GLACIER_0E6325403 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "Client" # App source code path
          api_location: "API" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "wwwroot" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

Comment: Are you using Azure Pipelines to build your project? Have you tried running it with debug mode enabled?

Comment: I'm using the Azure Github Action deployment. Azure deployment is new  for me, how can I switch to debug mode? Maybe it will work or deliver more information about the problem. If I deploy the same code directly from Visual Studio 2019 as a (not static) web app its running without any problems.

Comment: Can you check if this helps: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/156?